# PHP, regex and multi-level curly brackets

Tags: php, regex, brackets

I've got a string which consists of few sentences which are in curly brackets that I want to remove. That would be not that hard to do (as I know now.), but the real trouble is it's multilevel and all I want to strip is the top level brackets and leave everything inside intact. It looks something like this:

```
{Super duper {extra} text.} {Which I'm really {starting to} hate!} {But I {won't give up} so {easy}!} {Especially when someone is {gonna help me}.}
```

I want to create an array that would consist of those four entries:

```
Super duper {extra} text.
Which I'm really {starting to} hate!
But I {won't give up} so {easy}!
Especially when someone is {gonna help me}.
```

I have tried two ways, one was preg_split which didn't do much good:

```
$key = preg_split('/([!?.]{1,3}\} \{)/',$key, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$sentences = array();

for ($i=0, $n=count($key)-1; $i<$n; $i+=2) {
$sentences[] = $key[$i].$key[$i+1]."<br><br>";
}
```

Another one was using preg_match_all which was quite good until I realized I had those brackets multilevel:

```
$matches = array();
$key = preg_match_all('/\{[^}]+\}/', $key, $matches);
$key = $matches[0];
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Are your curly brackets guaranteed to be balanced?

Comment: @ghoti Yes, they are guaranteed to be balanced.

Comment: @Vulcan I have added info about what I've tried to the original post.

Comment: Are the top-level curly brackets always separated by a single space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a recursive expression like this:

```
/{((?:[^{}]++|(?R))*+)}/
```

The desired results will be in the first capturing group.

Usage, something like:

```
preg_match_all('/{((?:[^{}]++|(?R))*+)}/', $str, $matches);
$result = $matches[1];
```

Comment: Edit: It works and I get it, thank you very much, sir! Now I only need to understand what exactly this regexp does. :)

Comment: @moskalak, the elements in `$matches[1]`. Also welcome to SO, here best way to thank is by up voting. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
$x="foo {bar {baz}} whee";
$re="/(^[^{]*){(.*)}([^}]*)$/";
print preg_replace($re, "\\1\\2\\3", $x) . "\n";'
```

returns:

```
foo bar {baz} whee
```

Comment: Thank you for this proposition. It would be great, but it returns a string stripped of top-level brackets while I really need to create an array in which every string bracketed at top-level would be another entry.